# I cannot install python packages using pip3

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have installed pip3 successfully but whenever i try to install a package it comes up with this error(on macos high sierra terminal):

```
    libsuinput/src/suinput.c:25:10: fatal error: 'linux/limits.h' file not found
#include <linux/limits.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_4/bc_4xmsn63vb8kt8t5_g1wqm0000gn/T/pip-install-hby05qne/python-uinput/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_4/bc_4xmsn63vb8kt8t5_g1wqm0000gn/T/pip-install-hby05qne/python-uinput/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/_4/bc_4xmsn63vb8kt8t5_g1wqm0000gn/T/pip-record-xlhm8d89/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone help?

Edit: it returns the same error using normal `pip`

Comment: Please share exactly how you ran `pip`.

Comment: What are you installing? Which is the command that is returning this error?

Comment: How did you install pip3?

Comment: The command returning this error is `pip3 install python-uinput`

Comment: @Z4-tier it just came with python 3 i think

Comment: [`Python-uinput` is Python interface to **Linux uinput kernel module**](https://pypi.org/project/python-uinput/). You cannot install it at MacOS.

Comment: @fogc123 nope, Apple only ships with Python2. If you have pip3, you installed it from somewhere...you even said in the post "I have installed pip3"

Comment: @phd Is there an alternative for macos?

Comment: @Z4-tier  I have installed python3 from the official site.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

Comment: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Package i was trying to install was not compatible with MacOS.

Answer (score -1):

Python 2 is installed by default on Apple computers(check by `$ python --version`), but if you need Python 3 then you can use following steps-

1. Install Xcode and Homebrew. For Xcode do this-`$ xcode-select --install`. 
   Then install homebrew `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

To confirm Homebrew installed correctly, run this command: `$ brew doctor`

2. Install Python 3. Do this - `$ brew install python3`
3. Lastly, check your python version by `$ python3 --version`